# Paramiko - ssh server dies during command execution -> hang

Tags: python, ssh, timeout, paramiko, python-2.x

I am writing a little automation software in python 2.7 using paramiko. There's possibility that during the execution the remote machine (ssh server) dies, my paramiko client does not recognize it and hangs on the recv_exit_status() method. If I set a timeout either for the channel or for the transport, it does nothing. transport.set_keepalive() didn't help either.

```
channel = transport.open_session()
channel.exec_command(cmd)
exit_code = channel.recv_exit_status()
```

I've figured that another approach could also be good:

```
transport.set_keepalive(1)
channel = transport.open_session()
channel.exec_command(cmd)
while not channel.exit_status_ready():
    time.sleep(1)
    print "waiting", str(transport.is_active())
exit_code = channel.recv_exit_status()
```

But is_active() returns always True, it never changes to False, even after half a minute ... My sw is heavily threaded, so if this happens, the thread hangs on the blocking method recv_exit_status() forever and becomes a zombie, I cannot allow that (mostly from the professional point of view). Also, I know that active polling is generally bad programming technique, but I tried that anyway ... Thanks guys for your help

Comment: did you try to set a timeout on connect ?

Comment: Timeout on connect only defines how long should the connect method wait before failure upon connect (for how long should it try). I do have this one set, though mainly for many other reasons. I am already connected, I have issued the command and it is possible that the ssh server dies before completing the aforementioned command ...

Comment: I am sorry, I meant this other kind of [timeout](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/paramiko.Channel-class.html#settimeout)

Comment: Well actually, I haven't tried that. I most certainly shall do so. However I cannot allow the connection drop when there's long action going on and the server shouldn't respond at all eg. mysqldump into a file etc. These operations can take even minutes, and the connection cannot drop, I need a drop when the machine becomes non-responsive

Comment: I would move the problem upstream. I would drop a simple script on remote end to manage your commands. Then I'd invoke the script via Paramiko using "nohup" - putting the script in background - and I'd disconnect right away.
Moreover, you can program the script so that it can "netcat" the process results to another server or write them on a log.
Thus, I'd reconnect to check the logs or perform the next operations. In this manner, your process does not die if SSH freezes your connection up.

Comment: Well ... what about sshfs file operations, there is the possibility that the ssh machine that I am uploading the file to dies in the middle of the operation. Not that this your solution is bad, but in my opinion it is a bit of a Microsoft-like patch, does the job, but creates ten more other problems

Comment: There is absolutely no problem with deferring the check: it is just an asynchronous method. If it interferes with your architecture, it is not my problem: I do not know your software.
Have you eventually tried to experiment with 'settimeout' ? Note that if you configure the ssh server to send alive messages, waiting on a long command won't be a problem.

Comment: These machines are quite remote, I cannot change them at all. These are vegas-like gambling machines located all over central and eastern europe ... any change to the machines is out of the question. For security reasons I cannot tell anyone much further, it's a bit tricky getting help for this project :) I shall try the settimeout() right now